# how to render a component with window alert

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image]i try to render a component of all the products that are in the cart with window alert but i get just 'object object ' even when the component is empty.
[image][image]

i tried to pass it to a function but the result remains the same

Comment: If you use window.alert(), the only parameter is string and you can`t use it for react component rendering. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert

Comment: use a <dialog> element instead of alert()

Comment: i did it like this:
onClick={() => { <Dialog> <Cart /></Dialog> }}

but then i didnt get any render back

Comment: onClick will not render anything.  You have to include that dialog in render with some condition and change that condition in onClick, something like: onClick={() => { this.setState({ showDialog: true }) }}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not render a component in `alert` method.

You should pass a string to `window.alert()`.

**For example ✅:**

`window.alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");`

And the below is the **wrong way** ❌:

`window.alert(<Cart />);`

If you want to render the `<Cart />` in a modal you should build it yourself or find another solution.

**More explanation**:
The reason you get [object object] is that React components are all objects with some properties. And you can't pass an object to alert methods.

Although you can stringify the object using `JSON.stringify`.

Answer (score 0):

The string representation of a JavaScript object data type is indicated by the notation `[object, Object]` This is occurring in your case because you are trying to display an object using the alert() method. You cannot do it this way.

If you want to display that item detail in alter then do it in this way:

```
var obj = { name: 'Flower Pot', price: 2300, brand: 'Faux' };
window.alert(obj.name);
```

OR

```
var obj = { name: 'Flower Pot', price: 2300, brand: 'Faux' };
window.alert("You have added {obj.name} to the cart");
```

You can refer to [This article from Free Coding Camp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/object-object-in-javascript-meaning-in-js/) to understand more about the JavaScript Concepts.